# How do I make https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text= working without letting me login again when I'm already in Twitter web view

Tags: twitter

When I open a link, say `example.com/1.html` in Twitter app, there would be a webview. And in that `1.html` page, I have a link:

`<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello">Tweet</a>`

Clicking on that link, Twitter would guide me to post this tweet.

However, if the link was opened by `window.location.href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello"`, then Twitter would ask me to login again in the webview, which is very weird because I'm already logged in.

So I guess it's the `window.location.href` problem so I tried another way:

```
Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: '_blank', href: $b.attr('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=hello')}).click();
```

This time the `click()` trigger would never fired.

So, is it impossible for me to invoke a tweet action with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm noticing is that the `$b.attr(<url>)` in the `href` property should just be like this: `href: '<url>'`.  That looks like jQuery syntax to me, which is saying, "Get the value for the attribute `url` that's in the element $b.".

It'd be something like '`$b.attr("href")` or `$b.attr("url")` if you have an element of `<element href="<url>" url="<url>"><element/>"`.

I think that should fix your problem.

I can't tell if you want to have the user click to open the tweet, or if you want to auto-click for them.  Because that is what the `.click()` function does, is emulate a click on an element.

If you want the user to click, get rid of the `.click()`.

If you want to auto-open without a click, use `window.open('<url>')`.

That said, if you really want the `anchor` element, you can execute a click like this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
var $b = $("#link"); // has an attribute of 'url' with the twitter link
var a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), { target: "_blank", innerHTML: "Tweet", href: $b.attr('url')})
body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```